# How to dynamically add an element to the already rendered DOM in Next.JS?

Tags: javascript, next.js, web-component

I'm using Next.JS 13, and am currently trying to find a way to manually add component code to another **already** **rendered** element in the **DOM**. Here's the code for the component:

```
const layouts = {
    forgotPassword: () => {
        return (
            <>
                <ManualScrollerObject className="flex v center gap2">

                <h3>
                    Forgor your password?
                </h3> 
                <Field name="Tag/Email" id="user" />
                <Field name="Password" id="pass" icon="bx bxs-lock" type="password"/>

                <div className="flex v center gap1" style={{width: '100%'}}>
                    <LoginButton>
                        Sign in
                    </LoginButton>
                    
                    <p>
                       No, no, no <a href="/signup">take me back!</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="/forgot">Forgor your password?</a>
                    </p>
                </div>


                </ManualScrollerObject>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to add **this** element into **another** element which I'm getting using `document.getElementById()` while not **replacing** the **other** child.

I have created a seperate function for it, and here is what I tried:

```
function forgotPassword() {
    const loginScroller = document.getElementById('loginScroller');

    ReactDOM.render(
        layouts.forgotPassword(),
        loginScroller
    )    

    
}
```

**React.render()** will simply **replace** all the children within the element, which isn't what I want.
There is another solution in which I could append a seperate  element to my wrapper, and then make its children be the element that I actually want to add, however I feel that it is a very bulky and not-actually-to-the-point solution.

Are there any ways in which you could dynamically add the element in using a function like this?

Answer (score 1):

In React, we can use states to show or hide components. Here's an example:

```
 import { useState } from "react";

 function MyComponent() {
  const [showForgot, setShowForgot] = useState(false);

 return (
    <div>
      {showForgot && <ForgotPasswordComponent />}
      <button onClick={() => setShowForgot(true)}>Forgot 
 Password</button>
    </div>
    );
  }
```

This code uses a state showForgot to control if ForgotPasswordComponent is shown. Clicking the button sets showForgot to true, making the component visible.

Comment: So are you saying there is no way to just dynamically add and render elements based on user interactions?

Comment: React does allow dynamic rendering based on user interactions. However, rather than manually manipulating the DOM, React encourages using state and props to control what should be rendered. This makes the UI predictable and easier to understand. If you need to interact with non-React DOM elements, consider using React portals.

Comment: How would you use react portals in such a scenario? I simply want to dynamically add a component to another component on the go.

Comment: Facebook created React with a Virtual DOM so (lesser) developer don't mess with the DOM (there was no slow DOM, only stupid FB developers writing stupid code doing DOM access) So you have 3 options: Do it the React way, don't use React, or mess with the DOM and risk being punished by React